# How to store postgresql.conf outside of data dir?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-replication

I have used [these steps](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2013/02/16/zero-to-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-10-mins/) to setup database replication on Postgresql 9.4.

But, when using `pg_basebackup`, my entire database dir is copied, including the `postgresql.conf` file. However, that file is different for master and slave, so changes will be overwritten after starting the replication.

How can I run PostgreSQL with a custom data dir, but with the `postgresql.conf` outside of that dir?

I am using CentOS7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `--write-recovery-conf` to set up a standby server.

```
   --write-recovery-conf
       Write a minimal recovery.conf in the output directory (or into the
       base archive file when using tar format) to ease setting up a
       standby server. The recovery.conf file will record the connection
       settings and, if specified, the replication slot that pg_basebackup
       is using, so that the streaming replication will use the same
       settings later on.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html) contains instructions on how to pass postgres conf file as configuration parameter.

You can use a systemd unit on RHEL based systems to configure the cluster with custom name and/or configuration.